# Multiple reads and updates simultaneously on same row but different columns

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have a table with the following structure: one id column and multiple columns representing statuses of multiple processes executing at once. These processes will read and update the same rows possibly simultaneously, like this: read the id column, the corresponding status column of the process, do some processing and then update the status column. Is it possible to have deadlocks on the table row, even though the updates occur on different columns? If so, how could I avoid that?

Comment: The answer is "it depends" - my suggestion is wait until you have deadlocks before worrying about them.

Comment: Yes - for example if you are using transactions and you query id/status without `updlock` hint. Accessing different columns doesn't help - SQL server doesn't have column level locking.

Comment: I suggest that you have one row per process and ensure that you have PK and enable row level lock and disable page locking. You should only select/update the table based on PK. This is also an important read: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72369/risk-of-disabling-page-locking